# Does the word 'railing' bring into mind a posession fence, or something much lower?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, synonyms

While apparently it can be used in that manner, I fear that it is much more common to describe things like railings along stairs. The fact that the subject is a posession fence has already been established.

In general, I need a word for a fence with vertical bars, something that literaly and figuratively would invoke the feeling of 'looking through bars'. If the first thought about 'railing' is that of a waist-high obstacle, the effect would be completely opposite to what I had in mind and thus the distinction is very important to me. Also, 'railing' already happens to rhyme with what I wrote.

Comment: Railings can be any height. The ones at [Buckingham Palace](https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo/buckingham-palace-railings.html) in London are quite high. I'm not sure what you mean by a "possession fence". Is it a term local to where you live?.

Comment: You should know that when used with the "bar" sense, ***rails*** almost always refers to ***horizontal*** bars. But the word ***bars*** is effectively "neutral" in respect of horizontal / vertical orientation - and the specific collocation ***behind bars*** (in prison) will almost always be visualised as implying ***vertical*** bars.

Comment: I don't think fences have railings. They can have *rails*, but not railings. Perhaps you could use a name for a specific type of fence (e.g., [split rail fence](https://www.google.com/search?q=split+rail+fence&tbm=isch), [picket fence](https://www.google.com/search?q=picket+fence&tbm=isch)).

Comment: Can you provide a picture?  Or can you tell us how high the fence (or railing) is, how far apart the bars are, how thick the bars are, and what direction(s) the bars point?

Comment: A railing is a name for a particular type of fence made of vertical metal posts. The word can also mean one of these posts. Such a fence can, in fact be called 'railings'.

Comment: Pretty much as in Buckingham Palace. Here is another: https://cdn.gorilladash.com/images/media/912848/citywide-macedon-group-industrial-spear-top-original-5ce4d2777c6e9.jpg Does this type of fence have a more specific name? Differing opinions in the comments do not inspire my confidence in inducing the right association.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are railings

[image]

So are these

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that's what I pictured in my mind. If that's the primary name for this type of fence then I guess I'll run with it, if only because I already spent too much time on that poem.

Answer (score -2):

> In general, I need a word for a fence with vertical bars, something that literaly and figuratively would invoke the feeling of 'looking through bars'.

If the fence completely surrounds a small property, or small object (think 10-20 ft on each side), it's basically a *cage*.

It's not common to have long fence runs that are composed of immobile metal bars spaced closely enough where you can look through them but not fit through them.  A synthesized term like "prison-bar fence" or "jail-bar fence" would be needed.

Comment: Seems like it may be a cultural thing, but many are visible in films of New York, so I'm kind of surprised by this statement.