# A fence of steel or iron bars - does it have a name?

Tags: word-request, nouns

I need a word or words for fences which invoke a feeling of 'looking through bars'.

Take a popular type of fence around properties: typically black, spear-like bars with pointy tops, with a couple of horizontal rails: [picket fence](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Flda.lowes.com%2Fis%2Fimage%2FLowes%2FDP18-45266_082218_dt_bnr_2-2_MetalFencing%3Fscl%3D1&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.lowes.com%2Fc%2FFencing-gates-Building-supplies&tbnid=Yw9QK_AE7IQupM&vet=12ahUKEwjh9Pvd6aPsAhVYzCoKHYDgDowQMygPegUIARCdAg..i&docid=0zK_OSNzWzYVTM&w=496&h=250&q=fence&client=firefox-b-d&ved=2ahUKEwjh9Pvd6aPsAhVYzCoKHYDgDowQMygPegUIARCdAg).

[image: black steel fence]

I went through a couple of thesauruses and there seems to be precious little synonyms without going into things like barricades and ditches. The phrase I have in mind is: "I stare at/through the rusting railing" and I want to emphasise the aspect of an obstacle making something visible, but unreachable. I chose railing for rhyming potential, and while it can apparently be of any height, I fear it has wrong connotations: of something much shorter in general, with the focus on a single horizontal top rail like along stairs, which would severely clash with my intent.

Now, the fact that it is a property fence has been already established, so if saying something like 'looking through the pickets' or whatsies doesn't sound unnatural, it could certainly do. Sorry for being picky, but, one, I simply cannot rhyme 'fence' with something that would fit my purpose and, two, it is somewhat abstract and I don't think that it has an immediate visual association I am going for.

Comment: Railings can be any height.

Comment: You asked the same question [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/262127/does-the-word-railing-bring-into-mind-a-posession-fence-or-something-much-low/262132#262132) on October 7 2020. What is unsatisfactory about the answers you got there?

Comment: You're getting confused between a rail, which is horizontal, and railings, which are vertical. Also, they don't have to go together.

Comment: A fence with spikes on top (as you've pictured) is called a **palisade fence**, a **steel palisade**, or a **steel palisade fence**. This type of fencing is used for security; you can see through it (so trespassers cannot hide behind it like they could a brick wall), but trespassers are prevented from going over it (because of its height and spikes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the U.S. a *wrought iron fence* is the general term for what is being called railings in the other post.  I think it's another AmE/BrE thing.  I would never call those things *railings*.  *Railings* are what you hold onto when you walk up stairs, more appropriately called *bannisters*.

I imagine there will be a pedantic response as to the chemical composition of wrought iron and what configurations may or may not apply.  But *wrought iron fence* is understood as *metal barred fence (often black)*.

Comment: Steel Fence also seems to be used to refer to that type of fence. Probably a generational thing